# How do i finish a captcha without using a module like selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, captcha

I'm trying some web scraping, and i need to access a site from a terminal app. For this i intend to use a module like pillow to convert the image to text and then fill the entry field. But i am not sure how to take that input and pass the captcha for the website. The website is [here](https://rarbg.to/torrents.php).

Basically what i would like to do is

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://rarbg.to/torrents.php?search=some+show")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, features='html.parser')

# manipulate soup object and display all available torrents to user in terminal
```

But requesting the html like that sends me to this [threat detection site](https://rarbg.to/threat_defence.php) which has a very basic captcha on it.

Comment: You can use try to use playwright https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro or sleenium?

Comment: Both of those open up a browser in my background right? one i can handle from the python file? I just find that slower, and would like to not have to do it, as i am trying to do this with least latency

Comment: You can use headless mode of pw.

Comment: well the point is not that an interface shouldn't pop. It would still open an instance of the browser(headlessly) and using requests to just get the html (when i have no need to browse between pages) seems alot efficient